# how to show pdf in new windows from local path

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, pdf-viewer

I have converted a rpt file to pdf and saved it in a local system path via web.config and trying to open the pdf file after saving it , from the saved location. I am able to save it in the required folder and able to redirect the folder path to the new windows , but the folder path is appearing with out the '\' and with drive letter as small case

this is my code

```
var clsPrepareFile = new clsPrepareFile(General.ConnString());
dsUserMatrixReport = clsPrepareFile.UserGroupReport(sValue);
if (dsUserMatrixReport != null && dsUserMatrixReport.Tables.Count > 1 && dsUserMatrixReport.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && dsUserMatrixReport.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
//    if (dsUserMatrixReport != null )
{
    dsUserMatrixReport.Tables[0].TableName = "Inward_Report1";
    dsUserMatrixReport.Tables[1].TableName = "UserStatus";
    var rptDocument = new ReportDocument();
    //rptDocument.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle = "Inward_Report_" + txtFromDate.Text.Replace("/", "") + "_" + txtToDate.Text.Replace("/", "");
    CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
    //CrystalReportViewer1.ID = "Inward_Report_" + txtFromDate.Text.Replace("/", "") + "_" + txtToDate.Text.Replace("/", "");
    rptDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\Report\\UserGroupReport.rpt"));
    rptDocument.SetDataSource(dsUserMatrixReport);
    Session.Add("CR_Session", rptDocument);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDocument;
    string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportPdfPath"].ToString();
    string filename = "UserGroupReport" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".pdf";
    string pdfname = filePath + filename;
    rptDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, pdfname);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(string), "newwindow", "window.open('" + pdfname + "', '_blank')", true);
```

the script manager is redirecting to anew page and the url appears like this
"c:GeneratedPDFUserGroupReport20200415.pdf"

Comment: You should either save it under on of your own folders so that the redirection link to it can be created like `~/PdfReport/GeneratedPDFUserGroupReport20200415.pdf`. Otherwise, even if your link contains the `\`, any user who is not on the same machine will not be able to access it.

Comment: Or, you can save it to a temp path, implement a handler and redirect to that handler and server the pdf file from there. Look [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1452110.aspx?Creating+Pdf+file+through+binarydata+in+asp+net). It explains how you do it using a page or a http handler